# Yii radioButtonList: always takes the default value as the selected value

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

I have Yii radio button list as follows.

**forgotpassword1.php**

```
<?php echo  $form->radioButtonList($model, 'send_option', $email_exist); ?>
```

This is the action for forgotpassword1.

```
public function actionForgotpwd2() {
    $model = new User;
    $email_exist = array('mobile' => 'Send SMS to Mobile');
    $model -> setScenario('forgotpwd2');
    $model -> send_option='mobile';

    $postvars = array('conn' => Yii::app()->session['mobile']);
    $postRes = SCAppUtils::getInstance()->post_request('accounts', 'CheckAccount', $postvars);
    $out_arr = json_decode($postRes, true);
    //print_r($out_arr);

    if ($out_arr['success'] == true && $out_arr['email'] == true) {
        $email_exist['email'] = 'Send an E-mail';// = array('mobile' => 'Send SMS to Mobile', 'email' => '');
    } else if ($out_arr['success'] == false) {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $out_arr['error']);
        $this->redirect(array('forgotpwd1'));
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['User'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];

        echo Yii::app()->session['mobile'];

        //print_r($_POST);
        if(isset($_POST['User']['send_option'])) {

            //Yii::app()->session['send_option'] = $model->send_option;
            echo Yii::app()->session['send_option'];

            $postvars = array('conn' => Yii::app()->session['mobile'], 'send_type' => $model->send_option);
            $postRes = SCAppUtils::getInstance()->post_request('accounts', 'ChangePassword', $postvars);
            $out_arr = json_decode($postRes, true);

           // print_r($out_arr);

            if ($out_arr['success'] == true) {

                 $this->redirect(array('forgotpwd3'));
            } else {

                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $out_arr['error']);
            }

        }
    }

    $this->render('forgotpwd2', array(
        'model' => $model, 'email_exist' => $email_exist
    ));

}
```

Here I call a function named "ChangePassword()" from my backend application. One of the parameters passed to the backend is send_type: mobile or email. The problem is it will always takes mobile as the send_type.
I've used

```
$model -> send_option='mobile';
```

to set the default value as mobile.

Why it always takes mobile as the send type.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
<?=$form->radioButtonList($model,'send_option',array(1=>'Mobile',2=>'Email'))?>
```

In your `Acion` :

- To set the default value :

  ```
   $model -> send_option=1;
  ```
- To get the checked value (check whether it's `1` or `2`) :

  ```
   $_POST['send_option']
  ```